# Wrapping elements in a container using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a `.container` and 3 elements in it. The container is full width and its children are aligned to the left. I want to center everything.

This is a layout

```
.container
  .element1
  .element2
  .element3
```

And this is what I want

```
.container { 
  .invisible-wrapper-with-css { 
    .element[1-3] {
    } 
  } 
}
```

I don't want to add any html.

Is there a way to treat `.element[1-3]` as one item or is there a way to - using only CSS - wrap around them so that I can give the wrapper of the `.element[1-3]` children a `margin: auto` ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can treat them as one item, just put them inside a div, or use `.container` :)

Comment: No what i meant was to have this. `.container { .invisible-wrapper-with-css { .element[1-3] {} } }`

Comment: Please check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all the elements, just select every instance of a `div` child within the container.

```
.container {
  div {
  }
}
```

I'd recommend just using a flexbox displays, though:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Will give you spacing akin to table cells

```
.container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

Will essentially float all the elements to the center

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block` on the child elements and `text-align:center` on the container.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
}
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

On the whole though, I prefer flexbox.